# Setting the editing style on a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to set the editing style property of a UITableViewCell in a Cocoa Touch (iPhone) app.

For an example of what this looks like, check out the Contacts app, where you can see the little green plus sign to the left of some of the cells.

The UITableViewCell inspector in Interface Builder has an editing style drop down, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Likewise there is a CodeSense completion of an undocumented method called -setEditingStyle: for a UITableViewCell that doesn't seem to work either.

Is this a setting in the table view data source? Has anyone outside of Apple gotten this to work?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is indeed a method in the UITableViewDelegate:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Now I get a row of green plus signs!

Comment: Actually, this is a method of UITableViewDelegate, not UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 17):

Below is code gives you clear Idea about how to user Editing Style

```
 - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        { 
            return  UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        }
        else
        {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }
    }
```