# Add "Plus" button for AccessoryType TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, accessorytype

i'm trying to implement a TableView where each cell has a '`+`' button just like the iPod app when adding songs to a playlist.

The `cell.accesoryType` has only four values

```
UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton
```

`UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`

and

```
None
```

How can this be done? Do i need to create a custom button and set the `cell.accessoryView` or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Teo's solution works great, but it's not been posted as an answer, so I'm reposting it:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(addbuttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple variant of JosephH, for memory.

If you simply want a decorative "+" button and continue using the original didSelectRowAtIndexPath trigger, use :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

By disabling user interaction on the button, it will propagate pressure event on the underlying view : the cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a `custom cell`, then place a `button` on it at the right corner, just like where `accessory type` appears and assign it your '+' image to the button, so that you also "see the image" and get the "button action event".

Refer [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) tutorial for custom uitableviewcells.

Comment: Found solution         UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = button;

and created the event handling procedure

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event {
}

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look to [setEditing:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setEditing:animated:)
Check also [Setting the editing style on a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430538/setting-the-editing-style-on-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Oh yeah, this could be true. I couldn't understand that may be he wants to edit the table and add rows to it, which apple does giving green coloured '+' sign ?!