# Changing delete button to an add button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static table view that will act as a adder/editor of information in Core Data. Some of the information has multiple strings (like fields in iOS contacts). I want to change some of the delete button circles(-) with (+) buttons. How can I do this? I am going for something similar to contacts.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override this UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430538/setting-the-editing-style-on-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: Thanks! After making the style change and function I can't add a row with out crashing. How can I implement this with to-many relations in core data.